Can I hide the "New" link inside the calendar date using JSON
I'd like to hide the "+New" link inside the modern calendar using JSON. I used the  commandBarProps to hide the New button but it does not tie into the calendar functionality. Does anyone have any suggestions or syntax that would help?
